# Query without using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Having trouble with querying database.

```
Id parent pro_comp_id    year         type  financial  quantity

1   1           2      2011-08-15        1     10           12
2   1           2      2011-08-15        2     100         120 
3   1           2      2011-08-15        3     178         190
```

can any body tell me how to query this
so that it shows this three rows in one row.

```
financial  quantity financial  quantity financial  quantity 
  10      12          100     120           178    190
```

it can be done using the group concat
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(financial),parent from achivements group by parent
but I don't want to use Group_concat

Answer (score 2):

What you want is generally called a "pivot". Here's the standard way of doing that:

```
select
  year,
  sum((financial = 10) * quantity) as financial_10_qty,
  sum((financial = 100) * quantity) as financial_100_qty,
  sum((financial = 178) * quantity) as financial_178_qty
from mytable
group by 1;
```

This works because `financial = ?` is 1 for true and 0 for false.

This answer assumes that the values of "financial" are known and fixed.